# What is the difference between passing str.lower and str.upper as the key to list.sort?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
def problem4_1(wordlist):
     """ Takes a word list prints it, sorts it, and prints the sorted list """
     #print(wordlist)
     wordlist.sort(key=str.lower)
     print(wordlist)
     wordlist.sort(key=str.upper)
     print(wordlist)
```

This code sorts the list alphabetically. The output for both cases is the same. Is there any difference?

Comment: You will see a difference if you have characters that fall in between the range of upper and lower case letters… https://www.asciitable.com

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> sorted(['ß', 't'], key=str.upper)
['ß', 't']
>>> sorted(['ß', 't'], key=str.lower)
['t', 'ß']
```